# Eclipse access to workspace, compiler and export function from code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-generation

I have following tasks:

- Automatically generate java source files in the current workspace.
- Compile those files after generation.
- Export every generated and compiled class with needed libraries to runnable JAR file.

I already installed Eclipse SDK and I suppose what I need is to make my main class inherit some class from SDK and maybe load some other classes. But i don't know what do I need exactly and where to look. I'd appreciate some clues.

Comment: A search for `eclipse java tutorial` gets many potentially useful results. I suggest looking for one whose style you like, and following it.

Comment: What i mostly found is plugin developent, i.e. the code runs in separate eclipse enviroment. I'd like to have it quick and dirty, to run the code straight from the `main(String[] args)` method. Any thoughts about this specific request?

Comment: Try (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava). It is section 12, "Create your first Java program", in (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/article.html).

Comment: Sounds like a good task for a generic build tool like Maven or Ant. Not for Eclipse

Comment: Generate java source files from where? How? Compilation occurs automatically if you have set eclipse to build automatically. These tasks sounds like they should be done by ant and an ant builder, see http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-93_project_builder.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at M2T-JET to generate not only the Java files, but the project, any necessary folders and any other resources you need.  One of those resources would be a jardesc file which is used by the JDT to persist jar export options.  You can play around with those options to define the jar and export, then generate the jardesc file along with the other generated resources.

M2T-JET can be invoked programmatically, so once that single invocation generates your entire project, your plugin can make the call to the JDT to export the jar using the jardesc file.

Comment: Although this issue is over (because I chose simplier solution for my project) I appreciate your suggestion, because I'm interested on this topic and I'd like to experiment with M2T-JET during leisure time.